# Why does this code output 1?

Tags: php, switch-statement

```
$t = true;
switch($t)
{
    case 1*2:
        echo 1;
}
```

Comment: `var_dump((bool) 1);  // bool(true)`http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: from practical side this code is meaningless

Comment: Isn't `case` called when exactly matching?

Comment: Then why is it called when not exactly matching?

Comment: @kjy112 this question is more about how switch is working.

Comment: @assem: It seems you forgot to look at the documentation for this language feature before attempting to use it. The manual page is very clear that a loose comparison is performed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [manual for switch/case](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) says:

> Note that switch/case does loose comparison.

And `true == 2` [is true](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

Answer (score 4):

A `switch` statement does [loose comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose) between the tested expression and the expressions in the `case` labels to the type.

In this case, this means that it the compiler determines if `true == 2`. Since any nonzero integer compares equal to `true`, the branch is taken and `echo 1;` is executed.

Here's a less intuitive example where the exact same mechanism is in effect. You can explain it with the same logic:

```
$foo = 'hello';
switch($foo) {
    case 'A' || 'B':
        echo "Test succeeded";
}
```

I 've used this example in the past when teaching PHP to newbies, to get them to understand how a loosely typed language works.

Comment: Correct, but 1*2 is still 2 ;)

Comment: @TJHeuvel: I like addition more :)

Comment: @assem: To evaluate `'A' || 'B'`, first evaluate `'A'` as `bool` (operator `||` works this way). `'A' == true` so `('A' || 'B') == true`. So for the next step we test `'hello' == true`. Since any non-empty string compares equal to true, the branch is taken.

Comment: Just ran into something similar attempting `case is_null($value):` inside a `switch()` that does something really odd since `switch($value)` seems to change `$value = null` to `$value = [something falsey that evaluates to (bool) false, (string) "", or (int) 0]` - so `case is_null($value):` will *never* be true.

Comment: @CD001: That one's kind of amusing, but it can also result in the branch being taken: http://ideone.com/THhRCR

Comment: Only if the array itself is empty, not if an indexed value within the array is `null`; this is the testing I got to when I worked out what was happening: http://ideone.com/rXTnnp ... came onto SO to see if I could find a sensible answer as to *why* it was happening :) The fix was simply not to use a switch statement at all, but a series of if ... ifelse ... else statements :)

Comment: @CD001: That code looks like it should be written around `switch(gettype($value))`.

Comment: Maybe but then you're evaluating a string and hoping that `gettype()` always returns the same values in any PHP version you're deploying the code on (or any future version) ... far easier to just forget the switch altogether and just use `if(is_null($value)) ... elseif(is_bool($value)) .... ` and so on, there's only a finite number of simple data types to evaluate anyway.

Comment: @CD001: Meh... the return values of `gettype` cannot ever change due to BC breaks. But whatever works. :)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP (and in the most of programming languages) a non-zero value means true when is treated in a conditional statement. In this case *$t* (true) is equal to any number different than zero, so it matches the case condition. The output will be 1.