# switch statement outputs the number 1

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have a small problem, I have the coming swich statement.

```
            $usertype = 1;
       switch ($usertype) {

            case "0":
                echo require 'a.php';        
                break;
            case "1":
                echo require 'b.php';
                break;
            default:
               echo require 'c.php';
        }
```

Each of the three files I am calling contain the letter they are named by.
This statement prints '1' along with the letter ao the file name.

For example: if `$usertype = 1;` the output is `b1` and so on.

What can be the reason for it?

I receive the same output usinthe an if statement.

I have found this question asked before but it didn't helpd me so much.

[Why does this code output 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327335/why-does-this-code-output-1)

Any help would be great

Comment: can you show us what is in your a.php , b.php , c.php ?

Comment: a.php contains the letter a, b.php contains the letter b, c.php contains the letter c withiout any other html or php code

Comment: try this in a.php <? echo "a";die; , now what is the result ?

Comment: and one question , when it is a.php and c.php , what are the outputs ?

Comment: i copyed it to the b.php file, now it outputs only the letter b ($usertype = 1) without the number but it kills the rest of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try **without echo statement** if you use echo with require then it will return boolean value 0/1 so it's outputing 1 also.

```
   $usertype = 1;
   switch ($usertype) {
        case "0":
             require 'a.php';        
            break;
        case "1":
             require 'b.php';
            break;
        default:
            require 'c.php';
    }
```

Comment: i guess it wass the echo that make the 1 appear, maybe echo was confirming it is a true result. tnx you all

Answer (score 1):

First try without quotes:

```
   $usertype = 1;   
   switch ($usertype) {
        case 0:
            require 'a.php';        
            break;
        case 1:
            require 'b.php';
            break;
        default:
           require 'c.php';
    }
```

And also remove "echo"s when you call require.

The rest of problems are related to a.php, b.php and c.php .

Comment: tryed withiut the quotes as you suggested, still get the same output

Comment: I updated my answer. Please post contents of a.php, b.php and c.php via pastebin.com or gist. Probably the problem is in these files.